# SSH connection to Windows closed automatically using OpenSSH for Windows

Tags: windows-10, ssh, cmd.exe, openssh

I'm using OpenSSH for Windows (http://www.mls-software.com/opensshd.html). The sshd server is running fine on Windows, and I can authenticate myself from localhost as well as a remote Ubuntu computer. But after auth, the connection closes automatically without giving the terminal.
Sharing full debug level output of `ssh -vvv localhost`:

```
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/Muneeb/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to localhost ([::1]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t3 r-1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 4/5 cc -1)

Connection to localhost closed by remote host.
Connection to localhost closed.
Transferred: sent 1960, received 2776 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 261477.0, received 370336.8
debug1: Exit status -1
```

Here it automatically authenticates using the localhost public key, but before this I also tried logging in with a password, and it authenticated fine, but again the connection got closed with final exit status `255` instead of the `-1` seen in the case above.

Comment: We need to see a server log.

Comment: The openssh internal logs don't show any error for this event.

Comment: You need to increase logging level.